# how to correctly use Router in Laravel embed ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an application that requires the use of reactjs but it must be executed in a url other than home, for example
`site.com/app-react`
well, there's my div root
I have different components and in one of them i generate a Link
something like this

`<Link to = "test"> click </ Link>`

The URL generated is as follows `site.com/app-react/test`
I have a Router defined
`<Route path = '/test' exact component = {TestComponent} />`,
but when going to that URL the component never goes into action.

What is the correct way to do it in this situation?

```js
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>            
<Route path="" component={HomeComponent} />
<Route path='/test' exact component={TestComponent} />
<Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I think this route - `<Route path="" component={HomeComponent} />` won't work you should use this - `<Route exact path="/" component={HomeComponent} />`

Answer (score 0):

Paths are absolute (from root)

Try

`path={'app-react/test'}`

You could pull app-react out into a constant too.

Answer (score 0):

You should do [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter),

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/app-react"> //see the basename
  <Switch>            
    <Route path="" component={HomeComponent} />
    <Route path='/test' exact component={TestComponent} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And your `Link` should be,

```
<Link to="/test"> click </ Link> // renders <a href="/app-react/test">
```